# memcached is not working with my django site

Tags: python, django, memcached

I hit a problem that memcached doesn't work with my django site.

Here is my settings snippet:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS=600
```

I think memcached is running correctly,see below:

```
[root@speed-server operation_v8]# python manage.py shell
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.get('test')
>>> cache.set('test',1)
>>> cache.get('test')
1
>>>
```

I run memcached with -vv, however, when I make a post request, I didn't see any hit with memcached server, no log outputed.

I use django 1.6.11 and memcached 1.4.4

What's wrong here?

Comment: That is because POST requests are not cached. Only GET is cached.

Comment: Yes, I just find that...if I want to cache for post request, maybe have to use low-level cache api

Comment: This must be something really really important to override the whole purpose of using a POST